# Complex conjugate series

Tags: complex

I have a series like this one:

```
series = a[1][v](r-rp) + a[2][v](r-rp)^2 + O[r-rp]^3
```

where `a[n][v]` are complex coefficients of the series which are functions of `v` and `(r-rp)` is a real number. I want to `Conjugate[]` the series. However, Mathematica produces only (whatever I tried):

```
Conjugate[a[1][v](r-rp) + a[2][v](r-rp)^2 + O[r-rp]^3]
```

while I would like to obtain:

```
Conjugate[a[1][v]](r-rp) + Conjugate[a[2][v]](r-rp)^2 + O[r-rp]^3
```

I have tried e.g. `Conjugate[ComplexExpand[series,{a}]]` and variations with no good.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) of the series expression:

```
series //InputForm
```

> SeriesData[r, rp, {a[1][v], a[2][v]}, 1, 3, 1]

According to the documentation, and as you can see above, the 3rd argument consists of the coefficients of the series. So, to take the conjugate of a [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData) object, we just need to map [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate) at the right part:

```
conj = MapAt[Conjugate, series, 3];
conj //TeXForm
```

> $(r-\operatorname{rp}) (a(1)(v))^*+(r-\operatorname{rp})^2 (a(2)(v))^*+O\left((r-\operatorname{rp})^3\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Quick-and-dirty approach:

```
series = a[1][v] (r - rp) + a[2][v] (r - rp)^2 + O[r, rp]^3;
Assuming[r \[Element] Reals && rp \[Element] Reals,
  Conjugate /@ series // Simplify
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you explain to me, why for `test = a+b` `Conjugate[test]` returns `Conjugate[a+b]` while `Conjugate /@ test` returns `Conjugate[a]+Conjugate[b]`.

Comment: @fales have a look at [Map](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html).